# Converting pcapng file into csv file

Tags: coap

I'm using Ubuntu terminal and I'm running using

```
tshark -r file.pcapng -T fields -e 6lowpan.src -e frame.proto >file.csv
```

I also can't get protocol info. I want to convert a `.pcapng` file into a `.csv` file.

But, I'm not able to retrieve 6 lowpan source address using 6lowpan.src. In the `csv` file i am getting empty file without any output and also I want the output data in text format.

Comment: Please, explain it more.